# Getting users associates with a subscription ID in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, microsoft365

We have some Dynamics Sales Pro licenses that are expiring and were trying find the users with that license by the subscription ID in MSOLAccountSku; it returns nothing

Get-MsolUser -All | Where-Object {($_.licenses).SubscriptionIds  -match "bc95bb37-219c-4f43-9820-4e8663950903"}

I'm expecting to see all the users associated with the above subcription id; but, I don't get any results

Comment: Get all properties to make sure you are using correct WHERE.  Try : Get-MsolUser -All | Format-List